Going to X via Y
Say I'm buying a train ticket and want to go to Kyoto via Shinagawa, will this work:
ここから品川通って京都に行きます。
or:
ここから品川それから京都に行きます。

Look up ～を経て

Both will work, but:

You have to say 品川を通って京都に行きます in formal sentences.
The most explicit way of saying "go to Kyoto via Shinagawa" is 品川経由で京都に行きます.
Your second sentence does not have the meaning of "via". It sounds like Shinagawa and Kyoto are two independent destinations.

